# Create list item sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I want to use the action "create list item" in a SharePoint Designer workflow. My question is: if the list contain more than one content type, how do I choose the content type of the item I want to create?
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough - choose the "Reusable Workflow" option instead of a "List Workflow" when creating a new one inside SharePoint Designer. When you do so, on the first screen will be an option to scope the WF to the Content Type of your choice:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stevangelista. Unfortunately I'm working with SharePoint designer 2007 and it doesn't seem to work that way.
Do you know how to do it in 2007?

Comment: Ahhh, sorry - I missed that tag. Admittedly, it's been a while since I worked with SP2007 but I'll see if I can find or recall anything.